# How can I filter resources from an external assembly by type (text, icons, etc.)?

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

I already figured out how to load another assembly from my C# application, and extract the resources embedded to that assembly. My problem is that I'd like to filter the resources by type, i.e. I want to get only text resources, but not icons and other stuff.

The code I use at the moment looks like this:

```
string[] list = target.GetManifestResourceNames();         
foreach (var listentry in list)
{
    Stream resourceStream = target.GetManifestResourceStream(listentry);        
    var rr = new ResourceReader(resourceStream);
    IDictionaryEnumerator dict = rr.GetEnumerator();
    int ctr = 0;
    while (dict.MoveNext())
    {
        ctr++;
        string entry = dict.Value; //I'd like to know what kind of resource this is, how can I do that?     
    }
    rr.Close();
}
```

How can I determine which kind of resource entry I currently get, i.e. if it's an icon, a text resource, or something else?

Thanks a lot.